# Ionic cordova run Android Error

Tags: ionic, cordova-plugin

Minha aplicação ionic funciona no chrome porém quando vou mandar para o android ele me devolve esse erro. Alguem sabe como resolver ?

```
BUILD FAILED in 2s
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
21 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 20 up-to-date
(node:9604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\Abner\Documents\ionic\optech\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:65: AAPT: error: unbound prefix.

C:\Users\Abner\Documents\ionic\optech\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml:65: error: unbound prefix.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Abner\Documents\ionic\optech\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
(node:9604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Parece que o erro está no config.xml. Coloque ele aqui na sua pergunta para facilitar encontrar uma resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado pelo auxílio. Consegui encontrar o erro :)

Comment: Você pode responder sua própria pergunta. Se for um erro em comum, pode ajudar outras pessoas.